# Webpack chunk files on CDN server

Tags: angular, webpack

I have an angular 2 app and I am using WebPack for bundling. WebPack generates chunk files which are dynamically added to the webpage when it is loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" src="0.b422af7997bfeca78d4.chunk.js"></script>
```

I want these chunk files to be located on a CDN server. 
How can I add the CDN path in the src path of the script tag?

Answer (score 3):

If I've got your question correct you can use `publicPath` [Docs](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration)

In my proj I have smth like

```
output: {
  path: helpers.root('dist'),
  publicPath: 'https://mycdn.com/',
  // other config goes here
}
```

But this goes only for webpack prod build, so it doesn't put any cdn for the dev env and local ones.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the publicPath but it is not added to the chunk files it was only added to the assets and the vendor, polyfills and main javascript files. In your case is the path also added to the chunk files?

Comment: Nop, foa I have no chunk files added to the page, like to download 2 files (vendor, main) more then multiple parts of the same file. But I thought that publicPath will work for chunks either. Sorry, my answer now makes no sense